# File system timeouts on network mounts are insane

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, timeout

A few programs (FF and TB) on my *windows* laptop keep hanging on me and after some messing around I've figured out that it is when I try and do a "save as" but where the last location I saved to is on a network mount that isn't accessible right now. If I wait long enough, things time out and start working again.

*Is there a way to set that timeout to something like 10 seconds?*

Comment: Note that there's a tension here; you'd probably (usually) consider data corruption to be a worse problem than an OS hang, so it tends to try really hard to get your data written out. Programs tend not to be written with vanishing storage in mind.

Comment: the captain's right.  the better solution is: train yourself to save only to __local__ storage from firefox, __then__ drag-n-drop the file to the network storage.  use an "incoming" folder on your desktop as firefox's default save-to location.  (if i really need to download straight to network storage, i usually copy the link in firefox and use `wget` in Cygwin for the actual download.  this way firefox never gets the chance to become dependent on my network storage.)

Comment: @Captain Segfault: I guess I wasn't clear, the hang happens when I run "save as" and FF is looking to bring of the file location dialog box. I'm not concerned about other cases.

Comment: It is not just firefox.  I have found that on win xp machines, if you have a network share mapped, but it is no longer available it will hang your computer any time you try and do any file tasks.  I have tried to open my computer in this state, and waited for 10+ minutes while the entire machine hung.

Comment: Win Vista & 7 seem to limit their hanging on unavailable network resources on boot, instead of while you are working. I asked this on serverfault http://serverfault.com/questions/15206 to little help.

Comment: @BCS: you were clear.  any timeout you could change would be at the OS level, not in Firefox.  those changes would affect more than just the case you're concerned with.

Comment: @~quack: I *want* a OS level fix, not A FF/TB only fix. In my case if the network doesn't respond in a few seconds (2-3) it never will or something even worse is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look through these networking registry keys: [TCP/IP and NBT configuration parameters for Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;314053&x=17&y=5) though IMO the only option that looks relevant is `LmhostsTimeout` which has a default value of 6 seconds. Otherwise you can likely stick to the **NBT** (NetBIOS) settings as these relate to Windows networking and in particular, the open/save dialogs of all programs.

If you do change settings here, change them individually followed by a reboot (or possibly disable/re-enabling your network interface is enough) and test to see if it helps before setting the next one.